# How to connect redux with I18n file to switch language according to redux state?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, internationalization

I have used I18n.js library in react native to successfully change the language according to the defaultLocale choosed in I18n.js file.

But, the problem is when i used redux connect to perform state change, it gives me a lot of error ! I searched a library called react-redux-i18n but is there any way to solve this problem without using extra libraries ?

My I18n.js file :

```
  import I18n from "i18n-js";
  import en from "./locales/en";
  import tm from "./locales/tm";

  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  I18n.fallbacks = true;
  I18n.defaultLocale = this.props.selectedLang === "English" ? 'en' :'tm';
  I18n.locale = this.props.selectedLang === "English" ? 'en' : 'tm';
  I18n.translations = {
    en,
    tm
  };

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      selectedLang: state.auth.selectedLanguage
     }
   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(I18n);
```

How to perform this switch ? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You will have a lot of issues if you try to set the initial language with redux. I recommend you to use `AsyncStorage`.

On language switch - store the selected language and update `i18n`:

```
handleChangeLanguage = async (lang) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('lang', lang);

    const { i18n } = this.props;
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
}
```

On initial load of the application, check the `AsyncStorage` for preferred language:

```
 import i18n from 'i18next';
 import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
 ....

 const languageDetector = {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    detect: async (cb) => {
        // Case 1: The user chose his preferred language setting.
        const preferredLang = await AsyncStorage.getItem('lang');
        if (preferredLang) {
            return cb(preferredLang);
        }

        // Case 2: return the default language
        return cb('en');
    },
    init: () => {},
    cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        react: {
            wait: true,
        },
    });
```

Comment: Understood, what if user want to change language from inside the app ? Like setting page -> change language ?

Comment: @DazzilePro, `handleChangeLanguage` from my post is doing that -> it updates the newly selected language in `AsyncStorage` and updates the current `i18n` configuration. So, the next time when the user opens the application will use updated language from the `AsyncStorage`

Comment: I understand, it works on next time. What if there needs to be an live update, i am reloading or something which will change language when they changes and click on save language button !

Comment: And i am not using  'i18next' , just using pure i18n.js

Comment: I am not familiar with your `pure i18n.js` logic and I cannot help you :/ Maybe you need to rerender the component? But I recommend you to use https://react.i18next.com/, it will save you a lot of problems, especially with complex translations like currencies, variables in the translations, etc

Comment: `i18n.changeLanguage` is this default of I18n.js or feature of i18next ?

Comment: it is coming from `react-i18next` - https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage

Comment: Will i18next works with react native ? As it says for react ? And by the way i have created the whole translation in the en.js files using I18n.t(''), should i need to change that to something if i use this library ?

Comment: The library will work without any problems. If you config the module, `i18n` will be included in `this.props` and with `i18n.t` will work :)

Comment: Can you please share any tutorials ? or some guide to do this on react native ?

Comment: This is a working example: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/v9.x.x/reactnative-expo

Comment: ya but , its based on expo right ? any example without expo ?

Comment: Here is it... check the examples folder for more options: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react-native